# Deploy contract with web3 with ABI in JSON file give me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs, abi, solidity-0.6.x

I got problem with my deploy.js script to te deploy my smart contract with web3.

When I run it, I always got this error:

```
Attempting to deploy from account XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
(node:25929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at deploy (/louis/ethereum/deploy.js:16:53)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:25929) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25929) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

my deploy.js:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');
const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/MandatFactory.json');
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    'stable setup lunar pyramid another another apple install load citizen check fame',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/913ea7dd990444a58cc903fb97acc4a8'
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
        .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
        .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

I tried many things like
to change this:

```
const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/MandatFactory.json');;
```

to this

```
const compiledFactory = fs.readFileSync('../ethereum/build/MandatFactory.json', {encoding: "utf8"});
```

and change this

```
 const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
```

to this

```
const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory).interface)
```

I read that it could come from the version of web3, so I tried with many versions like 1.0.0-beta.35

But actually this my package.json:

```
"author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.9.1",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "next": "^4.1.4",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "solc": "^0.6.6",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "^1.0.17",
    "web3": "^1.2.7"
```

And this is my compile.js to compile my contracts in JSON file :

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const mandatPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Mandat.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(mandatPath, 'utf8');
//const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Mandat.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}; 

output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output['contracts']['Mandat.sol']) {
    fs.outputJSONSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + '.json'),
        output['contracts']['Mandat.sol'][contract]
    );
}
```

Thanks you for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: What's the content of MandatFactory.json?

Comment: @Ismael: The code in question (and `compiledFactory.interface` in particular) makes it pretty obvious that this is the output of running solc.js on a contract. The question is pretty much 100% identical to the one that I linked above.

Comment: @goodvibration You are correct, I wanted to make him  understand what went wrong, and how to fix similar problems.

Comment: @Ismael: I believe that it is explain pretty well in the answer to that question (though I'm not very objective on this since I'm the one who wrote it).

Comment: Thanks you it works, but now I have the same error as in the link you give me. It is about "You must provide the json interface of the contract...". I read that in my abi there isn't interface, do you have any post link with the answer please ?

Comment: I resolve it, it works now

Comment: @Ismael: Can you please review [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/82955/16043) and provide comments if you find anything inaccurate or incorrect (and perhaps also add an answer which explains the remaining gas missing)? Thanks.