# Ethereum cost - how does it work in memory

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

This is really bugging me and doesn't seem any article that can help at all.

wiki says further the gas costs for using memory:

> The fee for expanding memory is determined via a
> subtract-the-integrals method. Specifically, TOTALFEE(SZ) = SZ * 3 +
> floor(SZ**2 / 512) is the total fee for expanding the memory to SZ
> 32-byte chunks (note: partially filled chunks are counted, so 33 bytes
> = 2 chunks), and if a particular operation expands memory from size x to y, the additional gas cost is TOTALFEE(y) - TOTALFEE(x)

Now, I want to understand the formula idea.

So, I have:

```
//calling this costs 21394 Gas
function nice() external {
   
}

// calling this costs 21507 gas
function nice() external {
    uint128[1] memory t;
}

// THE DIFFERENCE HERE IS 113
```

Now, as I can see, we used maximum 2 chunks of 32 bytes. So putting in the formula will give us 6. How can it become 113 ? maybe I don't understand the additional cost - `TOTALFEE(y) - TOTALFEE(x)` ?  Can someone elaborate on this ?

**UPDATE 1**

I decided to compare two closer versions so that I could better understand it. So, We have 2 versions:

```
This gives us 21634
function test2() external  {
   uint128[22] memory t;
} 

This gives us 21640
function test2() external  {
   uint128[23] memory t;
}

So, there are 6 gas difference. Let's figure out how we can get the 6 by ourselves.
```

https://www.diffchecker.com/igIeqefv
In terms of opcodes, there's no actual difference, other than `codecopy`. If we look at `codecopy`, it says: `2 + 3 * (number of words copied, rounded up)`. So, let's calculate this for both versions. For version 1, it will be `2+3*22` = 68. For the second version, it will be `2+3*23=71`.

Now, we also have to count memory cost. The above seems like to be opcode costs. For the first version from the memory cost formula, we have - `22*3 +0 = 66` . For the second version, we have - `23*3 + 1 = 70`.

Now, let's sum those u. for the first version, we have `68 + 66 = 134`. For the second version, we have `70+71 = 141`. So, the real difference is 7 gas, when we saw that compiler difference was `21640-21634 = 6`.

What about the 1 gas ? This is very interesting.

**UPDATE 2**

There's another interesting scenario.

```
// This costs 21394 in remix
function test2() external  {
}

// Then I change it to . Now this costs 21409
function test2() external  {
        assembly {
            mstore(0x80, 10)
        }
}
So there is 21409 - 21394 = 15 gas difference
```

I decided to compare their opcodes. and in the second version, this is what gets added.

```
PUSH A          10  
PUSH 80         0x80    
MSTORE          mstore(0x80, 10)
```

Push is 3 gas, so we have 6 gas for 2 PUSH. and MSTORE is 3 . so we got 9.

Now, there has to be expansion cost, which seems to be 3. so we are left with 9+3 = 12.

How did we end up with the 15 gas difference instead of 12 ?

Comment: I'd suggest to compare both functions disassembly, and not the external gas consumption. Solidity compiler is extra careful and it might use some more bytecode for memory house keeping even when it is not needed.

Comment: This is the difference . - https://www.diffchecker.com/J6aDfjvj .  The first and second difference are negligible, assembly is still the same. The 3rd one is the actual one. Left side we can see big red. If you look closely, there's only 1 `mstore` operation. It just doesn't make sense why the difference is 113 gas .

Comment: @Ismael I think, I realized that those opcodes that are more in the first version, causes gas costs to grow, since each opcode also costs gas. So, to sum up, each opcode costs its own gas , storing in memory also costs gas. those 2 are a little bit different kind of gas because one is related to the actual storing , another one is for just using opcode , which mightn't be storing anything at all, but still costs gas. do you agree ?

Comment: If you agree, how can I test the above memory expansion function ? the formula didn't make much sense, so I wanted to test it myself. any way you can think about how I can test the formula ?

Comment: @Ismael I Updated the question.

Comment: Running update 2 on remix debugger mstore costs 9 in total, and memory increase by two slots 0x60 and 0x80.

Comment: @Ismael, how can memory increase by 2 slots when we only store number 10 in 0x80 only ?

Comment: it could be because of zero-slot. not sure what it uses for , since we don't have dynamic arrays, but there's no other explanation. don't you agree ?

Comment: Memory usage consider the highest modified slot, it doesn't track individual slots. If you modify slot 0x80, it will charge for all inbetween slots, even when they weren't used, like 0x60.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118740/discussion-between-nika-kurashvili-and-ismael).

Comment: Ismael, I really, really, really would appreciate you taking a look at this.  I spent so much time. :( @Ismael HERE IS THE LINK: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92619/ethereum-solidity-gas-cost-wrong . This will be the last question about gas cost.

Comment: @Ismael Hi Ismael, Just to avoid the chance of you missing it out, I added something in the chat. The chat can be viewed on this question [Let us continue this discussion in chat]...